# Control an Android phone remotely from the computer

Tags: cyanogenmod, touchscreen, remote-control, broken-screen

I have a Nexus 4, I've had it for 2-3 years running in Cyanogenmod rooted with no problems. It fell many times but nothing bad ever really happened to it until yesterday.

It fell and had a tiny crack in the screen, then the screen was no longer responsive. I've seen many people with cracks in their screen able to use their phones but I guess that wasn't the case for the Nexus.

Now since there's nothing wrong with the phone beside the screen, is there a way to control it from my PC? I find a screen replacement would cost as much I bought it.

Comment: Have you tried the app called [AirDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid&hl=en)?.

Comment: [How to control your Android via PC - CNET](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-control-your-android-via-pc/) is the key to follow.

Comment: @GulamMohammed I can't control the phone at all to install apps on it.

Comment: Well, Softonic provides desktop app of [AirDroid]( http://m.en.softonic.com/app/airdroid-desktop)

Comment: @GulamMohammed OK, I'm going to try airdroid. I'll update you to know if everything works. Phone doesn't work but usb adb is working so ill push the apk there.

Comment: airdroid does not solve the problem as it requires me to actually have set it up on the phone before installing and i've never installed airdroid until today. I can't set up airdroid remotely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found another app called [Droid Explorer](https://github.com/camalot/droidexplorer) on GitHub. Download the required setup (x86 or x64) and install it.

After installation, follow the video of [ANDROID Controlled from PC (How-To Remote Control ANDROID Phone)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eEeHaszOMi0) by MobileTechVideos. The video shows the complete procedure of using Droid Explorer.

**Requirement:** Android SDK

Comment: This is a very nice solution, however, I also found a similar one here:http://marian.schedenig.name/2014/07/03/remote-control-your-android-phone-through-adb/ which got the job done  exactly as I wanted last night I used it on Linux and just had to modify the config file to my adb location which was /usr/bin/adb.